# Автоматический переход в начало textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```
<textarea placeholder="...." onkeydown="" class="js-textarea hrobutt1244" style="width: 100%;">
```

Народ подскажите, пожалуйста. Как сделать так что бы при вставке текста в textarea курсор сразу возвращался в самое начало. т.е. если я вставляю текст - курсор после вставки переходит в начало этого текста, а не в конец как установлено по умолчанию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для одноразовой вставки (любое изменение будет снова устанавливать каретку в начало):

```html
<textarea placeholder="...." onkeydown="" class="js-textarea hrobutt1244" style="width: 100%;" oninput="this.selectionStart=this.selectionEnd=0;"></textarea>
```

Если нужно, чтобы работало только при вставке <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd>:

```js
document.querySelector('.js-textarea').addEventListener('paste', function() {
  setTimeout(() => this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = 0, 10);
});
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="...." class="js-textarea hrobutt1244" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
```

Если каретка нужна в начале текущей вставки:

```js
document.querySelector('.js-textarea').addEventListener('paste', function() {
  let nPos = this.selectionStart;
  setTimeout(() => this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = nPos, 10);
});
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="...." class="js-textarea hrobutt1244" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Так всегда будет в начале курсор для ввода. Вроде как надо только при paste

Comment: Думаю автору вопроса будет несложно пройтись по документации и использовать соответствующее событие [вставки](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/onpaste) ;)

Comment: @Crus: дополнил.